# XSLT compile error yet Xpath evaluates

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to use a style shhet to transform this XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<h>
  <m>
    <c name="HM">G</c>
    <c name="HL">20</c>
    <c name="HS">f</c>
  </m>
  <m>
    <c name="HM">L</c>
    <c name="HL">30</c>
    <c name="HS">t</c>
  </m>
  <m>
    <c name="HM">S</c>
    <c name="HL">10</c>
    <c name="HS">t</c>
  </m>
</h>
```

Here's the stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//h/m/c[@name='HM' and text()='G']/following-sibling::column[@name='HS']"/>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This template match expression line does not work, gives this error xsltCompileStepPattern : 'child' or 'attribute' expected

However on the command line the match expression give this result

```
xmllint --xpath "//h/m/c[@name='HM' and text()='G']/following-sibling::c[@name='HS']" test.xml 
<c name="HS">f</c>
```

Could someone kindly explain why this is and how I can fix my stylesheet

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual error is because "following-sibling" is not allowed in a path in a template match. (Your expression is also looking for `column` which is not in your XML, but I assumed that was a typo, and it would not actually cause an error anyway).

You haven't specified what you are actually trying to do, but based on your current attempt it looks like you are trying to match the "HS" `c` node that follows an "HM".

Try reversing the logic and use this expression instead

```
<xsl:template match="/h/m/c[@name='HS'][preceding-sibling::c[@name='HM' and text()='G']]"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I think understand now